# Implement a semaphore-like functionality between JS and a C++ app

Tags: javascript, c++, semaphore

I am trying to find way to create a semaphore like functionality between a JS script run on a browser and a C++ program.
My application is a real-time log file viewer. I have an application that logs periodically to a file. I am going to extract some information from that file and display on a browser using JS. But the problem is this file can get pretty big and having to go through the entire file periodically in JS is very slow and ineffective.

So I my thinking was to have a separate application read the file periodically and write to another file 'only' the new content. Then the JS can go through that smaller file and update its values. This can be done effectively with `seek` and `tellg` functions in C++.

But I can't have the JS and the C++ program running asynchronously. I need some way for the JS and the C++ program to sync with some kind of locking mechanism. For example C++ will take the lock and then read the log file and update the new contents. Then when the lock is available JS will lock it and display the contents and so on. Of course I need some kind of counter to make sure the C++ program will not overwrite before the JS reads the data.

Anyway you get the idea what I want to achieve. I came across 'Native Client' by Google. This was perfect as I can easily exchange messages back and forth between the JS and the C++ program. But unfortunately when I use Native Client it doesnt allow me to read/write to local files. So my C++ program has no access to read the log file.

Other way was to use Web Storage, but there is no consistent way for the C++ program to read the data written by the Web storage. So that doesn't work either.

If you have any idea please do share. Thanks.

Comment: What is the relationship between the executable and javascript client browser? They are both on the same machine? Is the browser loading a local file written by the executable? Have you considered making the executable server the data over http?

Comment: Yes. They are both on the same machine and the browser is reading a local file written by the executable. I havent' thought about making the executable serve data. That seems a little too complicated. But there seems to be no other alternative. Thanks.

Comment: you can try using websocket to communicate with browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First option** I can suggest is using a **websocket server** implemented in c++.

**Second option** is (quick and dirty);

1. write a short program: acquire.cpp which acquires the lock and output an html header and message "OK" or "error".
2. write another program: release.cpp which releases the lock and outputs an html header and message "OK" or "error".
3. write functions in JS to send POST/GET requests to those (**using CGI**) after compiling them
4. Keep using those locks in your main.cpp as usual.

Those will solve the problem.